# linking a button to a certain sound in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, avaudioplayer

I'm using avaudioplayer and want to add a button to play the sound but i'm not sure how to.
Here's current code:

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h

@class AudioPlayerViewController;

@interface AudioPlayerAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    AudioPlayerViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AudioPlayerViewController *viewController;

@end



#import "AudioPlayerAppDelegate.h"
#import "AudioPlayerViewController.h"

@implementation AudioPlayerAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

found some sample code in the dev fourums!!